# Xcode, OS X: viewing a simple NSMutableArray

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, nsarray

Relative newbie question.  My app has a simple NSMutableArray of NSNumbers.  (about a dozen integers) I'd like my UI to have a view displaying the numbers so that the user knows what's in the array.  I want the contents of the view to be current, so I think I want a binding to the array (or its contents).  Is there a simple way to do this?

I think I can figure this out if I change my model so that the NSMutableArray contains a custom class having a setter and getter to a declared property (following Lucas' YouTubtorial on NSTableView bindings), but I would think that there might be a simpler way, one that allows me to use my array of NSNumbers.  I'd have to do a fair amount of editing if I have to redo my NSMutableArray.  Thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use plain old NSNumbers (or anything else) in your model, no need to use a custom model class.  However, you could create an NSValueTransformer subclass if your model data needs any special formatting for your view.

In your NIB you will have an NSTableView and an NSArrayController.

Bind the Value property of a TableView column to the NSArrayController, controller key = arrangedObjects, Model Key Path is empty (because you're viewing the NSNumber instance itself, and not a property of NSNumber).

Bind the Content Array property of NSArrayController to your model (the NSMutableArray of NSNumbers).  This is probably a property on your view controller or app delegate.

That's about it.  You can also hook up buttons to the `add:` and `remove:` actions on the NSArrayController, and you'll be able to add and remove items from your array.

Also, you need to send a KVO notification whenever your NSMutableArray changes.  For example, say your NSMutableArray is exposed through a property called "numbers":

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"numbers"];
[_numbers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:123]];
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"numbers"];
```

You get these notifications for free if you set the "numbers" property to a new value:

```
self.numbers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:foo];
```

Comment: You'll also get these notifications for free if you implement and use properly named mutable accessor methods. Read more here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html . In short, you implement:

`- (NSUInteger)countOfNumbers;
- (NSNumber *)objectInNumbersAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)insertObject:(NSNumber *)aNumber inNumbersAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)removeObjectFromNumbersAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)replaceObjectInNumbersAtIndex:(NSUInteger) withObject:(NSNumber *)aNumber`

Comment: Implement *and use*. Simply implementing them will not enable you to talk to the array directly and get KVO notifications; you need to send yourself those accessor messages (or wrap everything in `will`/`didChangeValueForKey:`) to cause notifications.